# "Illegal character in path" using XSLT

Tags: c#, .net, xslt, illegal-characters

I'm getting an "Illegal character in path" exception when I call the Transform method of the XslCompiledTransform class.

Here is my code :

```
// Maybe there is a problem in this path 
string xsltPath = @"..\..\HtmlAttributesParser.xslt";

XslCompiledTransform xsltCompiled = new XslCompiledTransform();
xsltCompiled.Load(xsltPath, new XsltSettings(false, true), new XmlUrlResolver());
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

xsltCompiled.Transform(content, XmlWriter.Create(output));
```

There isn't any * ? " < > | in my path so I wonder why I get this Exception.

Regarding to the Exception message, there is no connection between the value of my content var and this exception right ?

Edit : Here is the content which works on an online XSLT tester

```
<div class="pk-link">
<a href="/STORE/Pages/myPage.aspx" url="/STORE/Pages/myPage.aspx" width="" heigth=""  target="_blank">
    <img border="0" src="/link_download.gif"/>
      Download
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: The error does not come from xsltPath/Load but from Transform. What do you pass in content? a path? a uri?

Comment: Post your XSD file content (in short if possible)

Comment: The content is the string of data to Transform. Here it is some HTML code. I don't understand why the problem can be due to the content because I've tested my transformation on http://www.xsltcake.com, and it works with this content.

Comment: I tried with a content string like "<main></main>" and the same Exception has been thrown. Any ideas?

Comment: The problem is in the XSLT. Do you have a linenumber (reported along with the error)? What code do you have at that line in the xslt?

Comment: Somebody had a similar problem here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/xmlandnetfx/thread/62fa2364-76de-43e8-931c-8bb37280c3e7/ and was able to resolve it. Not sure if you've got the same problem, but it might help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have a string with XML input then you need to use an overload of the `Transform` method expecting an `XmlReader` or `XPathDocument` (or more generally `IXPathNavigable`) created over that string so do e.g.

```
string result;

using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(content))
{
  using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(sr))
  {
    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {

       xsltCompiled.Transform(xr, null, sw);

      result = sw.ToString();
    }
  }
}
```

The overloads of the Transform method that take a string as the first argument expect a file path or URL, not the XML input.

Comment: Thanks a lot, sorry for this thread I was sure that the first parameter was the XML input.

Comment: Also applies to Load (I was loading an xslt store in the resources).